# ContextMenuStrip Opening Event

Tags: contextmenustrip

I have a ContexMenuStrip cms on my project. And i'm trying to add this event to my code, but it isn't triggering when i right click on my mouse.

The menu appears but the event isn't called.

```
void cms_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        // Code...
    }
```

I'm trying handle this event in order to prevent the cms from opening if some conditions meet.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: please attach full code

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the relevant code.

```
 private void MenuTeam_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (dgvMatches.CurrentCell != null && (dgvMatches.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 3 || dgvMatches.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 6))
        {
            dgvMatches.CurrentCell.Value = e.ClickedItem.ToString();
            dgvMatches.CurrentCell = null;
        }
    }
    private void MenuGolos_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dgvMatches.CurrentCell != null && (dgvMatches.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 4 || dgvMatches.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5))
        {
            dgvMatches.CurrentCell.Value = e.ClickedItem.ToString();
            dgvMatches.CurrentCell = null;
        }
    }


    void MenuGolos_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvMatches.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != 4 || dgvMatches.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex != 5)
        {
            MenuGolos.Close();
        }
    }
```

The 2 first events are working just fine. The thrid one isn't beeing triggered.

Thank you!